# Мышка иногда перестает кликать

Tags: ubuntu

Время от времени моя мышка начинает игнорировать клики.
То есть она двигается по всему экрану, но клики воспринимает, как будто она застряла в последнем окне на определенном месте. Если это такое место, что клики ничего не делают, то ничего и не происходит. Но один раз мышка решила, что она застряла в калькуляторе на кнопке "квадратный корень", и в каких бы окнах я ее не нажимала, калькулятор каждый раз извлекал  квадратный корень.

Клавиатура работает, но как будто в том же самом окне, даже если открыто другое окно.
Можно Alt+Tab ом открыть другое окно, в нем можно печатать, но мышка в нем не кликает.

Проблема возникла довольно давно, я долгое время думала, что это система тормозит.

Поменять мышку или включить ее в другой USB порт не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот [баг](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1181666) известен еще с версии 13.04, но сейчас, в версии 18.04 и выше он совсем разбушевался. Существует несколько вариантов плохого поведения мышки.

Народ в обсуждении бага обвиняет gnome-расширения.
Я пробовала их деинсталлировать командой

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

и это не помогло. Но может кому-то поможет?
Вернуть обратно можно командой

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Также я пробовала по их совету команду

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

вообще компьютер завис, пришлось перегружать.

А работает такой обходной путь:
нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>
заходим заново на свой счет, и мышка возвращается к полноценной деятельности.
Пока опять не застрянет.

Пожалуйста, если эта проблема вас затрагивает, зайдите  на https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1181666 и отметьтесь.